# Select a duplicate row with one unique_id and second unique_id diferent ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose that you have this table:

```
ID  |   DOC |   DOC_ID  |   TYPE
1   |   A   |   B       |   A
2   |   A   |   B       |   B
3   |   BB  |   CC      |   A
4   |   BB  |   DD      |   A
5   |   E   |   F       |   A
6   |   E   |   F       |   B
7   |   E   |   F       |   B
8   |   G   |   H       |   A
9   |   G   |   I       |   A
10  |   G   |   I       |   B
11  |   G   |   H       |   B
```

I need to identify the information in this table with all of this cincuntanses:

- DOC field has to be the same
- DOC_ID field has to be different
- Have more than 2 rows per DOC register

How to get the information like the next table?

```
ID  |   DOC |   DOC_ID  |   TYPE
3   |   BB  |   CC      |   A
4   |   BB  |   DD      |   A
10  |   G   |   I       |   B
11  |   G   |   H       |   B
```

Ive tried to do with Group by, count(doc_id), and couldnt get the result

Comment: What is a DOC register? How does BB have **more than** two rows per such register?

Comment: sorry for my bad english, that means 2 rows per DOC value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking window functions.  These are the rules you describe:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by doc, doc_id order by doc_id) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by doc) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and cnt >= 2;
```

I think these are the rules you want:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by doc, doc_id order by doc_id) as seqnum,
             count(distinct doc_id) over (partition by doc) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, What i have to do if i want to get rid of null values in "DOC" column?

Comment: @yulian6766 . . . Your sample data has no `NULL` values, so I don't really know what you are referring to.  But `where doc is not null`.